# display image next to field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to validate a field such that if it has a value, a 'tick' symbol is displayed next to the field.

I have the following javascript function which does the validation

```
function validate_this_field(field_value, field_id)
{
   if($j('#' + field_id).val() ) {   
   $j('#' + field_id ).addClass('mandatory_field_completed');
   }
}
```

**css code**

```
.mandatory_field_completed{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: green;
    background:url(../images/tick.png) right no-repeat;
   padding: 4px 4px 4px 34px;
}
```

The problem with the above css is that the image is displayed inside the field. I would like to display the 'tick' image outside and next to the field being validated.

Any suggestion is most appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think, if possible, you'd be better having the image and the input field floating next to each other in a container element. The image woiuld be set to visibility:hidden. When the field is validated add a class to the container which then sets the image to visibility:visible.

Comment: Cheers..that's what I am going to do :)

Comment: In general UI elements that are images should be backgrounds because they are not part of the content. An inline image will work, but is less semantically valid.

Answer (score 1):

Put image next to the div with `display:none` style and then show it:

```
function validate_this_field(field_value, field_id)
{
   if($j('#' + field_id).val() ) {   
       $j('#' + field_id ).addClass('mandatory_field_completed')
           .next().show(); // show next element after div
   }
}
```

or, you can have some control container div and set style to it with image in background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it outside the fields, you will have to apply the image to the background of the wrapping element:

```
<div class="tick"><input class="txtInput" type="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .txtInput {
        width:200px;
    }

   .tick {
       background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/90/Check_mark_23x20_02.svg/19px-Check_mark_23x20_02.svg.png);
       padding-right:20px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position:205px 0px;
   }
```

Add the class to the wrapper upon validation.